# I can't figure how to make this php form to work

Tags: php, forms, simple-form

I can't figure how can I make this simple PHP form to work.
What Am I do wrong?

```
  <?php
$first = "firstNumber";
$second = "secondNumber";
$second * $first = "calc";
$calc = "calc";
echo("" . $_GET['$calc'] . "<br />\n");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="new.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="firstNumber" id="first">
        <input type="text" name="secondNumber" id="second">
        <input style="background-color: #0094ff;" type="submit" name="calc" value="שלח" id="second">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: $second * $first = "calc"; what is this?

Comment: `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` are available in `$_GET['firstNumber'], $_GET['secondNumber']`. Otherwise, you would be depending on the old and deprecated and dangerous `register_globals`.

Comment: Whats are you expecting to happen and what actually does happen?

Comment: $second * $first = "calc"; is very strange. wtf!

Comment: You have invalid HTML as you used the id `second` twice. Also `$_GET['$calc']` won't work. Use `$_GET['calc']` or in your case as you defined `$calc` in the line before `$_GET["$calc"]`. Not to mention that this will simply return the value of the submit button.

Comment: $calc = "calc"; lol, not wrong but funny

Answer (score 6):

### In short

I guess you want something like

```
<?php
$first = $_GET["firstNumber"];
$second = $_GET["secondNumber"];
$calc = $second * $first;
echo $calc . "<br />";
?>
```

### Expanded

But in complete, because if you run this you get warnings because you didn't send the form

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET['calc'])) {
      $first = $_GET["firstNumber"];
      $second = $_GET["secondNumber"];
      $calc = $second * $first;
      echo $calc . "<br />";
   }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="new.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="firstNumber" id="first">
        <input type="text" name="secondNumber" id="second">
        <input style="background-color: #0094ff;" type="submit" name="calc" value="שלח" id="second">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Example

http://codepad.viper-7.com/LZ7phd

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I keep the name of the input field and the id of the input field the same. This may or may not help you.

```
<form action="new.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="firstNumber" id="firstNumber">
    <input type="text" name="secondNumber" id="secondNumber">
    <input style="background-color: #0094ff;" type="submit" name="calc" value="שלח" id="second">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['$calc']` represents nothing here.
You must use `$_GET['firstNumber']` and `$_GET['secondNUmber']`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `id` property of `input` to call the values of those fields. You must use `$_GET` and the **name** of the input field. You're also assigning variables incorrectly:

```
<?php
$first = $_GET[firstNumber];
$second = $_GET[secondNumber];
$calc = $second * $first;
echo $calc . "<br />\n";
?>
```

Comment: just one edit, GET and POST values are fetched using name, not id parameter. id can be used in javascript to fetch value.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic Thanks for that. It was a typo.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick answers :)

Comment: NP. i guessed that, comment was for OP who seems to be learning PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You're not pulling your parameters from the `$_GET` stream:

```
$first = $_GET['firstNumber'];
$second = $_GET['secondNumber'];
$calc = $first * $second;
```

All your fields are passed in the `$_GET` stream.

`$_GET['calc']` is actually your submit button by the way, not your calculation variable.